# JS - Iterating array with one condition and calling function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to execute a function for all "on" rows with same userId from this array:

```
productIds, userIds, status
[ 'com--test,LFutx9mQbTTyRo4A9Re5ksjdnfsI4cKN4q2,on',
  'com--test,LFutx9mQbTTyRo4A9Re5ksjdnfsI4cKN4q2,off',
  'com--fxtrimester,LFutx9mQbTTyRoldksfns4A9Re5I4cKN4q2,on',
  'com--fxyear,LFutx9mQbTTyRoldksfns4A9Re5I4cKN4q2,on'
  'com--fxtrimester,LFutx9mQbTTyRoldksfns4A9Re5I4cKN4q2,off',
  'com--fxyear,LFutx9mQbTTyRoldksfns4A9Re5I4cKN4q2,off',
  'com--fxyear,SEzlksdfMpW3FxkSbzL7eo5MmqkPczCl2,on',
  'com--fxtrimester,SEzlksdfMpW3FxkSbzL7eo5MmqkPczCl2,on' ]
```

So for this

```
  'com--fxtrimester,SEzlksdfMpW3FxkSbzL7eo5MmqkPczCl2,on',
  'com--fxyear,SEzlksdfMpW3FxkSbzL7eo5MmqkPczCl2,on',
```

or this:

```
'com--fxtrimester,LFutx9mQbTTyRoldksfns4A9Re5I4cKN4q2,on',
  'com--fxyear,LFutx9mQbTTyRoldksfns4A9Re5I4cKN4q2,on'
```

Execute something like:

```
`setProductsToUser(productIds,userId)`
```

-- First parameter is array `([com--fxtrimester, com--fxyear])` and the second is a userId (string) `(SEzlksdfMpW3FxkSbzL7eo5MmqkPczCl2)`

So if this is going to be a long (around 500 rows not too long) array I would want that is fast... efficient.

```
So long I have: 

var fL = 0;
fL++
unique.forEach(function(data){
  fL--
  if(fL=0){

   for (var h = 0; userIds.length  >= h; h++) {
    if( status[h] == "on"){
      for (var k = 0; userIds.length  >= k; k++) {
        if(status[k] == "on" && userIds[h]==userIds[k] && productIds[h]==productIds[k]) {
          productsOn.push(dataArray[0]);
          userId = userIds[h];
        }
      }    
    }
  }
}

var dataArray = data.split(',');     productIds.push(dataArray[0]);userIds.push(dataArray[1]);status.push(dataArray[2]);

}); 
setProductsToUser(productIds,userIds)  //where I place this?
```